# Why 'extern' storage class works differently in functions?

Tags: c, extern, storage-class-specifier

The following snippet works fine

```
extern int i;
int i;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Here what I got is, 'i' is declared and then defined. Since there is only one definition so thats perfectly fine.

```
int main(){
    extern int i;
    int i;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the above one gives the following error

```
new.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
new.cpp:5:6: error: redeclaration of ‘int i’
  int i;
      ^
new.cpp:4:13: note: previous declaration ‘int i’
  extern int i;
```

Whats the problem here? Here also there is single definition of 'i'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the difference, you need to get familiar with a concept called *tentative definition* in C. To quote the C standard:

**C11, draft, §6.9.2, External object definitions**

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
>   without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
>   the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative
>   definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
>   definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
>   external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
>   as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
>   unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

What you have in the first snippet is only a tentative definition for `i`. You can have as many tentative definitions for an object as you want (but only one definition is allowed):

```
int i; // tentative definition
int i; // tentative definition
int i; // tentative definition

int main(void) {
   return 0;
}
```

is valid.

Here, `i` has external linkage and tentatively defined. If `i` is defined in somewhere in the same translation unit, then that'll be the actual definition of `i`. If there's no other definition of `i` is found in the translation unit, then this becomes the full definition as if it was defined like:

```
int i = 0;

int main(void) {
   return 0;
}
```

But the second snippet `int i;` is *not* a tentative definition. Only objects with external linkage can be defined tentatively. In second snippet, The declaration `extern int i;` says `i` is defined elsewhere with external linkage. But the next line `int i;` says `i` is defined with no linkage (local automatic variables do not have any linkage -- this is *not* a tentative definition). So there's a conflict of definition for `i`. Hence, the first one snippet is fine but second isn't.

Comment: first time I encountered the word "tentative definition". I work in C++ and I don't think such thing exists there.

Comment: Yes, C++ doesn't have tentative definitions.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, there are two declarations of `i` in one scope.  One says "there is a variable `i` defined outside this function"; the other says "there is a variable `i` defined inside this function".  Without a new scope, that isn't allowed.

The rules are different inside and outside functions.

Note that you could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 21;

int main(void)
{
    extern int i;
    i = 37;
    {
    int i = 57;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles OK (unless you include `-Wshadow` in your compilation options when using GCC or Clang), and produces `57` and `37` on the output (as pointed out by [CoffeeAndCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2297448/coffeeandcode) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535793/why-extern-storage-class-works-differently-in-functions/32535916?noredirect=1#comment52929867_32535916)).

See also [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/1433387#1433387)

Comment: should add that that example would print `57` then `37`