# Functions and variables scope in C

Tags: c, function, variables, scope

Why we don't use extern when using function from one .c file in another .c file , but we must do extern for variables case? Is it related to linker?

Comment: functions are externally visible unless declared `static`. Same as file-scope variables

Comment: Not clear for me: do you mean without an header file with function prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are extern qualified by default (unless you change it to internal with `static`). For example,

```
int func(void) {
}

extern int func2(void) {
}
```

Both `func` and `func2` are external. The `extern` keyword is optional for external functions.

Comment: So by default, functions are already externally visible (externed), but variables are not?

Comment: @Lazar: Sure, they are.

Comment: Variables (at file scope) are external as well if they do not have `static` qualifier. The rules are a bit more complicated for variables but for functions, it's quite straight forward. You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32536140/1275169) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, function names act just like variable names, but function prototypes are `extern` by default.

From [cpprerefence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration#Explanation):

> If a function declaration appears outside of any function, the identifier it introduces has file scope and external linkage, unless static is used or an earlier static declaration is visible.

Comment: Probably I need coffee, but compiler will give you _implicit declaration of function_ if you define a function in different module and try to call it from another module. And, also, it assume function return an int. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LPs that's if no declaration is visible from the call site. But I understood the question as "why don't function declarations need the `extern` keyword like variable declarations do".

Comment: Well, probably I'm not getting the sense of question. I asked to OP.

Comment: @Quentin you understood it well.

Comment: @LPs No modern C compiler will give you an implicit function declaration. That huge language design mistake was fortunately removed from the language in the year 1999, 17 years ago.

Comment: @LPs Use `std-c11 -pedantic-errors` and it will give you errors for C language violations.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `.h`file,declare functions you want to use in the other `.c` files and `#include` the `.h`file in the other `.c` files.

Answer (score 0):

Demo program,

**one.c**

```
#include "one.h"

void func1() //defination
{
    //code
}
```

**one.h**

```
void func1(); //declaration
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "one.h"

int main()
{
    func1();
}
```

Then compile program in Gcc Linux : `gcc main.c one.c`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Let consider you have one .c file as process.c and you declared it in process.h . Now if you want to use the function from process.c to suppose tools.c then simply #include "process.h" in tools.c and use ther function. The process.h and process.c file should be in your project.

*process.c file*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include "process.h"
unsigned int function_addition(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
 unsigned int c = 0;
 c = a + b;
 return c;
}
```

*process.h:*

```
<bla bla bla >
unsigned int function_addition(unsigned int a, unsigned int b);
<bla bla bla >
```

*tools.c file:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include "process.h"
my_tools()
{
 unsigned int X = 1, Y = 9, C = 0;
 C = function_addition(X,Y);
}
```

All these files are in one project.

Comment: You want to include process.h into process. c as well. Doing so the compiler will notify you in case the function's declaration form the .h file and its definition in the .c file were not in sync any more.

Comment: @alk yes you are right. We have to include process.h in process.c too.